# iBeacon Reliable/Unreliable

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I am working on my home automation app.  I am using estimotes iBeacons and what I want to do is give my Home Automation Control the ability to know my proximity in my home.  Each iBeacon is given a virtual switch on my Home Controller and when I come in contact with a iBeacon my device either in foreground or background will update my control to turn on my switch for when I am near a beacon and turn it off when I have wondered away from my beacon.  All of this works perfectly and I am loving it, however some of my conditions rely on me to be in a proximity for a period of time, and what I am noticing is after a couple of minutes or even after a half hour of being near a beacon, the iPhone 5s basically drops its connection and then fires it back up, causing it to perform an exit (turn off my virtual switch) and then immediately perform an enter (turn back on the virtual switch).  As you can imagine this is very annoying to the wife and myself in the middle of the night when the bedroom lights start to flicker on and off because of the exit/enter.  I have read about people having this problem and tried everything I have seen on the internet to no avail.

What I noticed is that whenever a monitor crossing has been crossed for a iBeacon, both the didDetermineState and the corresponding Enter/Exit call back functions are called.  What can I do to get this to stop occurring?  I can provide code examples if needed but this is more of a general question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common problem with iBeacons (and wives of geeks like us), and the simple solution is a software filter.  You must ignore region exit events that last only a few seconds until you verify that there is no subsequent entry event.

You can do this by creating a variable (e.g justExitedRegion) that tracks these events.  When you get an exit region notification, set justExitedRegion=YES and start a five second timer.  When the timer goes off, if justExitedRegion==YES, perform your exit logic normally and set justExitedRegion=NO.  Otherwise skip processing the exit logic.

Meanwhile, if you get an entry notification and justExitedRegion==YES, set justExitedRegion to NO and skip your entry processing.

Comment: One thing that I have noticed is there is no set length of time.  From my logging there are ones that last 50 seconds and then a re-entry.  I actually had one that was 15 minutes long and it re-entered when I moved my phone.  Its like the location signal is shutting down when the phone sleeps.  On top of that this is all being done in the background and I am not sure I can sleep 5 seconds.  I think apple really needs to harden this technology if we want to see it make a big splash on the mobile mark.  Any idea how to handle this in the background?  Thought of ranging but isn't working right!

Comment: I was going to also suggest you enabled raining on exit for about 30 seconds to perhaps force a quicker re-connect, along with the software filter idea...

Comment: In the background, you have five seconds to work with, which is why I suggested that number (you may have to back it off to 4).  I am surprised to hear you are getting longer dropouts, that is something I have not witnessed.  In the cases where you move your phone, are you sure you are not on the edge of the transmitter range?  Also, always enable ranging when you do monitoring as it makes the phone detect more quickly.  It is also good for spitting out debug about your signal strength.

Comment: It was a distance issue with some of the drop outs so that seems to be resolved.  I stopped using the ranging stuff when I setup the justExitedRegion BOOL last night.  It went the whole night without switching my wife nor I out of the room.  I will review logs to see how many time the OS tried to do it and that trick cancelled it.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know whether you're at home or not at home, you could fire up the GPS on the phone and check your location.

Assuming you have a wifi network at home that your iPhone sees regularly, geolocation will work very well even inside the house where there will be no GPS signal. It will know no the latitude/longitude of the wifi base station and give that as your current location.

So use iBeacon as your primary location detection, but verify the data it gives you using GPS.

Also, you should contact Estimote to be sure you don't have a faulty unit or something. It is pretty new hardware, there could be issues.

Comment: I don't want to fire up my GPS indoors, that is why I have iBeacons, so I guess if they are that unreliable then how could these ever be applied to realworld?  We should have to check to make sure it is right.  I mean apple puts a 20 second delay when you exit just to make sure you are right about exiting, but then there are these one offs where the signal just drops.

Comment: @Jarod Welcome to the world of analogue electronics. Radio signals are extremely frustrating to work with, a moth flying around the house will either weaken or strengthen the signal, maybe alternate between them depending on the wing position. Your neighbour turning on the microwave will affect things. iBeacon doesn't use as much battery power as GPS because it doesn't waste energy trying to be reliable. If you need a consistent data feed, then you're using the wrong technology. iBeacons are a tool that can be used in many situations, but it's far from perfect and not suitable for everything.