# iBeacons with app killed

Tags: ios7, ibeacon

I am testing our iBeacons on iOS 7.1 and I can detect beacons correctly when I am in foreground and invoke the app from the background. However the issue comes when user has killed the app. The "didDetermineState" callback get invoked twice when I am in the beacon region while the app is killed. Am I missing the obvious or has anyone experience this same behavior ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have seen this happen not just when the app is completely killed, but in other cases, too.   You will need to add filtering logic to your region callback methods, so if you get multiple calls it doesn't cause trouble in your app.

Another common issue is that you will get an exit region notification, followed within a couple of seconds by an entry region notification.  Again a software filter is the way to deal with this.  An example of a software filter for iBeacon callbacks is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23146840/1461050).

Comment: Hey David , Thanks for your timw. Your posts regarding the beacons stuff have been immensely helpful to me . Keep it up !!