# Why didDetermineState: forRegion: method called twice

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager, ibeacon

I'm testing Apple's AirLocate app and a little confused about behavior of this method.

My code:

1. I create a CLBeaconRegion and add it into dictionary like a key

   ```
   self.rangedRegions = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

   CLBeaconRegion *region = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:[[NSUUID alloc]initWithUUIDString:@"E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0"] identifier:@"Group 57"];
   self.rangedRegions[region] = [NSArray array];
   ```
2. Then i start monitoring and ranging

   ```
   for (CLBeaconRegion *region in self.rangedRegions)
       {
           [self.locationManager startMonitoringForRegion:region];
           [self.locationManager startRangingBeaconsInRegion:region];
       }
   ```
3. Delegate method

   ```
   - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
   {
       if(state == CLRegionStateInside)
       {
           NSLog(@"INSIDE REGION %@",region.identifier);
       }
       else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside)
       {
           NSLog(@"OUTSIDE REGION %@",region.identifier);
       }
       else
       {
           return;
       }
   }
   ```

Thats what i see in logs:

```
2014-11-24 16:10:42.482 AirLocate[741:60b] OUTSIDE REGION E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
2014-11-24 16:10:42.977 AirLocate[741:60b] OUTSIDE REGION Group 57

2014-11-24 16:11:31.061 AirLocate[741:60b] INSIDE REGION E2C56DB5-DFFB-48D2-B060-D0F5A71096E0
2014-11-24 16:11:31.656 AirLocate[741:60b] INSIDE REGION Group 57
```

**Why this method called twice both for CLRegionStateInside and CLRegionStateOutside?**

**Why why the console output UUID first line and then the identifier of the region? As u can see in the code it should be only region.identifier (i.e. "Group 57") in console.**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23146840

Comment: I just cleaned up the code and reinstall application as @davidgyoung wrote and it helped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are ranging two different regions from a previous run of your app.  Try uninstalling and reinstalling.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I just created another simple app with monitoring and ranging and everything works fine. I also cleaned up the code in AirLocate App and it works as expected too.